# Why CDN DNS settings requires A

Tags: dns, cdn, incapsula

Probably simple question and I miss something trivial but...
Typical CDN incapsula setup is:

- domain.com A record to incapsula IP
- subdomain.domain.com CNAME record to incapsula.host

Why is A record used? Why don't use CNAME record for root domain also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you cannot have a CNAME record for the root domain if you want to have other records under that same domain. This is not allowed by the DNS specification, specifically in RFC 1034 (http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1034.html)

> If a CNAME RR is present at a node, no other data should be
>   present; this ensures that the data for a canonical name and its aliases
>   cannot be different.  This rule also insures that a cached CNAME can be
>   used without checking with an authoritative server for other RR types.

If you had CNAME flattening then you "could" do it.

Answer (score 0):

Whether CNAME record can be used for root domain is decided by the DNS service provider for that domain. It has nothing to do with the CDN provider for that domain.

CNAME to root domain is not standard DNS function, thus why many DNS service providers do not support it. That is also why root domain has to point to A record from CDN provider in some situation.

In other situation where DNS service provider does support CNAME to root domain, and you configure root domain to point to CNAME, you will still find a A record when dig it, this is called CNAME flattening.

Take my this site whatsmycdn.com for example, it is actually pointing to CDN CNAME, but you only see CDN virtual IP when digging it as a result of CNAME flattening:

```
dig whatsmycdn.com +short
110.232.178.193
```

Answer (score 0):

Most DNS provider will not allow you to point root domain to other record then A record, the reason for that is that RFC rules prohibits that.
The best practice will be to point the root record as instructed by Incapsula and use their management console to point the root domain to the WWW one to avoid latency (The CNAME uses Geo-location).